# Error reported by instance running in Docker

Tags: docker, cnosdb

When I used the 'Docker logs' command to view the content of CnosDB, I found some errors:

```bash
2023-09-15T09:27:05.451961010Z  INFO tskv::compaction::job: Starting compaction on ts_family 9
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: invalid character 'l' after object key:value pa
```

This is the command I executed:

```bash
docker logs <container_id> --tail 100
```

I don't know how this came about, let alone how to solve it